# .NET - Reducing GC contention on array creation

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, garbage-collection, contention

I have some code that deal with a lot of copying of arrays. Basically my class is a collection that uses arrays as backing fields, and since I don't want to run the risk of anyone modifying an existing collection, most operations involves creating copies of the collection before modifying it, hence also copying the backing arrays.

I have noticed that the copying can be slow sometimes, within acceptable limits but I am worried that it might be a problem when the application is scaled up and starts using more data.

Some performance analysis testing suggests that while barely consuming CPU resources at all, my array copy code spends a lot of time blocked. There are few contentions, but a lot of time blocked. Since the testing application is single threaded, I assume there is some GC contention magic going on. I'm not confident enough in how the GC works in these scenarios, so I'm asking here.

My question - is there a way to create new arrays that reduces the strain on the GC? Or is there some other way I can speed this up (simplified for testing and readability purposes):

```
public MyCollection(MyCollection copyFrom)
{

    _items = new KeyValuePair<T, double>[copyFrom._items.Length]; //this line is reported to have a lot of contention time

    Array.Copy(copyFrom._items, _items, copyFrom._items.Length);

    _numItems = copyFrom._numItems;

}
```

Comment: When really (and deeply) immutable, you don't need to copy in this example. Just share the _items.

Comment: Have you considered not using large arrays but smaller ones (split them and hide them under your own collection class) anda copy on write mechanism? Page the array into pages of lets say 4mb...

Comment: @DukeOf1Cat TomTom is referring to reducing pressure on the Large Object Heap (which is used when a single object hits a certain size, arrays tend to be the most likely to go here). The LOH has some deliberate drawbacks to cater for, well, large objects. General advice is to try not to use it, hence chunking large arrays into smaller arrays. [This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Writing-High-Performance-NET-Code-Watson-ebook/dp/B00LR30G4O) covers this topic a little.

Comment: OH, I should clarify, I really wrote it poorly last time - the collection is immutable when "finalized", but it should be possible to create a copy of it, modify the copy, and then "finalize it". I guess immutable is the wrong word - more like read only.

Comment: @TomTom No, I have not considered that option. I can do so and run some testing. Copy on write seems like a good idea too - the collections can share _items and only copy it when it wants to modify it. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Exactly. It will definitely reduce the amount of memory you use. If that works I can put it in as answer.

Comment: I'm testing using shared _items and it seems to work fine, it drastically reduces the need to copy in my app. I have not yet tested avoiding the LOH but I think I might not need to. Both Henk and TomTom gave me the idea to share _items, could one of you please put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure what's going on here, but contention is a *threading* problem, not an array copying problem.  And yes, a concurrency analyzer is liable to point at a *new* statement since memory allocation requires acquiring a lock that protects the heap.

That lock is held for a *very* short time when allocations come from the gen #0 heap.  So having threads fighting over the lock and losing a great deal of time being locked out is a very unlikely mishap.  It is not so fast when the allocation comes from the Large Object Heap.  Happens when the allocation is 85,000 bytes or more.  But then a thread would of course be pretty busy with copying the array elements as well.

Do watch out for what the tool tells you, a very large number of total contentions does **not** automatically mean you have a problem.  It only gets ugly when threads end up getting blocked for a substantial amount of time.  If *that* is a real problem then you next need to look at how much time is spent on garbage collection.  There is a basic perf counter for that, you can see it in Perfmon.exe.  Category ".NET CLR Memory", counter "% Time in GC", instance = yourapp.  Which is liable to be high, considering the amount of copying you do.  A knob you can tweak if *that* is the real problem is to [enable server GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thread being blocked for a substatial amount of time is exactly what happens - or at least it's what VS's performance analyzer tells me. Or am I misinterpreting "Exclusive blocked time"?

Comment: Ah, yes thank you. I wasn't challenging your answer, just want to make sure that I understand what's going on. You tone suggested that it was unlikely that I really had problems with blocked time so I want to make sure that I'm not making a mistake in using "Exclusive blocked time" as a definite tell that this is what is happening.

Comment: You never even mentioned that you used a concurrency analyzer, I had to guess at it.  Clearly I cannot derive accurate facts based on guesses only, that requires a properly documented question.

Comment: You're right, the question did not make that clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept of **[persistent immutable data structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence.aspx)**. This is one of the possible solutions that basically let's you create immutable objects, while still modifying them, in a memory efficient way.

For example,

Roslyn has a SyntaxTree object, that is immutable. You can modify the immutable object, and get back modified immutable object. Note that the "modified immutable object" has possibly no memory allocations, because it can build on the "first immutable object".

The same concept is also used in Visual Studio text editor itself. The `TextBuffer` is immutable object, but each time you press a keyboard button, new `immutable TextBuffer` is created, however, they do not allocate memory(as that would be slow).

Also, if it's true that you're facing the issues with LOH, it can help sometimes when you allocate the big memory block yourself, and use that as "reusable" memory pool, thus avoiding GC completely. It's worth considering.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good solution, I'll read up on that. Though it seems hard to build support for modifications such as removal and reordering. Add seems easy - just add an object that references the previous objects, sort of like a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can wait for the new runtime in 2015 though that will use SIMD instructions for the Array.Copy operation. This will be quite a lot faster. The current implementation is very sub-optimal.

At the end, the trick is in avoiding memory operations - which sometime just is not possible.

Comment: The OP reports blocking _before_ Array.Copy is executed.

Comment: There saddly is nothing you can do here except not allocating so many large objects.